RP2040 ADC calibration (schematic)
I was working with Raspberry Pi Pico ADC pins, and found out there are minor errors in the Pico ADC (12bit) values:

When the ADC pin is connected to ADV_VREF, the readout value is 4083 (average of 100k samples) but I expect 4095.
When the ADC pin is connected to AGND, the readout value is 14 but I expect 0.

I think there is need for calibration. To calibrate, I think there is need for a schematic. I did my first try with the simplest schematic I could imagine, like this:

With above values (14 and 4083) it can be calculated that:

Ru=291*RI
Rd=339*RI

I've gone one step further and used a 100 kΩ 1/4 W resistor:

then

When the input is connected to ADV_VREF, the readout value is 3881
When the input is connected to AGND, the readout value is 97
with 1, the RI is calulated 5185 Ω
with 2, the RI is calulated 15762 Ω

The values do not match so I think the schematic is not correct. Is there any better schematic that can describe the internals of the RP2040 ADC pins?

Section 4.9.2. SAR ADC of the RP2040 datasheet has the following description of the ADC input characteristics:

The ADC input is capacitive, and when sampling, it places about 1pF across the input (there will be additional capacitance from outside the ADC, such as packaging and PCB routing, to add to this). The effective impedance, even
when sampling at 500ksps, is over 100kΩ, and for DC measurements there should be no need to buffer.

In the datasheet can't find any suggestion for how to calibrate the ADC.
Characterizing the Raspberry Pi Pico ADC could be useful for how to perform a calibration, as has the following in the list of issues:

The biggest thing is that the ADC has some significant DNL issues. It looks like those were caused by a systematic error in the capacitors for the DAC portion of the SAR ADC.


Sad. That's a nasty error, wouldn't want to use that for any application that requires much performance.

The linked analysis is very thorough and well worth reading.

Finally i did a simple linear calibration. thanks anyways

I'm not sure this is the correct approach, since there are many sources of error that might not behave like the circuit you've shown. For example, the 'zero' error could be negative, perhaps. Usually this kind of ADC input draws a current that varies with the sample rate and something like the difference from  Vref/2, so the 100kΩ will introduce additional errors.
I suggest a simple linear interpolation for calibration. Apply a voltage V1 that is near (but above) zero, and take a heavily averaged reading Z1. Apply a voltage V2 that is near (but below) full scale and take a heavily averaged reading FS1.
Then, from those two readings, you can use an equation to linearly map the reading to whatever you need.
